how to remove Zakra Shop? beginner question
Hi guys I hope all is good!
I'm new to WordPress and i had a problem where every time i try to install a new theme this theme keep showing and block the new theme that i installed, can anyone please help me removing this Zarka Shop from my dashboard?
(https://i.sstatic.net/XBzqo.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/ej5HG.png)
Thank you!
I tried to uninstall all the themes but this Zakra shop keep showing

"Zarka Shop" is your website's name. In the WordPress dashboard, go to Settings > General; set Site Title value.
